# Restricting AWS S3 bucket to only certain instances for /GET requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Folks,
  We have (sensitive) images and video stored in an S3 bucket.  Would like to only allow our web server instances to be able to access the data in these buckets via http calls.  What are our options?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to access them via straight http?  If you leave the files in the default permissions (only accessible to your account), you could use an SDK to retrieve the files.  Your instances would need access and secret keys to make requests to the files.

Comment: How did you go with this? Any closer to a solution to your question?

Answer (score 3):

Create a policy that will restrict access:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html

http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

Comment: Why not this? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html

Comment: Why not? It seems like overkill. There's simply no need to authenticate like that. Policies are simple to use and from my understanding fit your use case perfectly. S3 is already restricted to the bucket owner by default so simply connect on the web server as that user, or create a new user and make a new policy to allow that user.

Comment: The counter question is: What does REST Authentication provide, that policy does not ... that you need! You haven't really gone into detail in your question, ie do you need to sign requests, do they need to expire after some time etc. As your questions stands policy seems like a perfectly reasonable solution, in fact I think that's the way you should go!